# Incorrect Empirical Semivariogram Value

Tags: geospatial

My gstat program for calculating empirical semivariogram on walker lake data is as follows

```
data = read.table("C:/Users/chandan/Desktop/walk470.csv",sep=",",header=TRUE);
attach(data);
coordinates(data)=~x+y;
walk.var1 <- variogram(v ~ x+y,  data=data,width=5,cutoff=100);
```

The result is as follows

```
 np      dist    gamma
1   105  3.836866 32312.63
2   459  8.097102 44486.82
3  1088 12.445035 60230.48
4   985 17.874264 76491.36
5  1579 22.227711 75103.67
6  1360 27.742246 83595.83
7  1747 32.291155 91248.20
8  1447 37.724524 97610.65
9  2233 42.356048 85857.03
10 1794 47.537644 93263.63
11 2180 52.295711 98282.98
12 2075 57.601882 91589.39
13 2848 62.314646 91668.70
14 2059 67.627847 95803.45
15 2961 72.310575 91975.76
16 2240 77.648900 95858.87
17 3067 82.379802 88123.56
18 2463 87.641359 87568.94
19 2746 92.334788 97991.56
20 2425 97.754121 93914.31
```

I have written a code of my own version of the same peoblem using classical sample variogram estimator. The number of points, dist are coming exactly as in the output. But the gamma value is not same. Why is that and what should I do to make it exactly same with gstat output?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: How did you compute gamma?

Comment: @Edzer 1/2N(h) SUM(z(i)-z(j))^2 I have also tried the cressie's robust estimator...but that is also not same

Comment: I'd guess there is something wrong with your implementation. Have you tried with a trivially small data set, say n = 2 or 3? This is btw not a question about gstat, but about your own code.

Comment: @Edzer yes. I will double check my code. I just wanted to know what method is used to calculate gamma.

Comment: @EdzerPebesma Three points are `11 8,8 30,9 48`. Distance are `18.02776,22.20360,40.04997`. Gstat gamma `3.635071e-27,2.524355e-27,1.009742e-28`. My gamma is `25177.68,0.0,25177.68,`

Comment: The z values are `0,0,224.4`